# Retornar dados de uma URL com Query String

Tags: php, laravel, restful

Existe um serviço que preciso enviar dados via query string e ele me dá um retorno JSON, porém, não estou conseguindo obter esse retorno, ele não envia a query string.

```
$url = 'https://www.servico.com.br?nome=abc&cpf=abc&cep=abc'
```

Tendo a variável `$url` eu tentei das formas abaixo:

```
$dataReturn = file_get_contents($url);
//Retorna uma mensagem de erro dizendo que os parâmetros não foram passados.
//Como se tivesse enviado apenas: www.servico.com.br

$dataReturn = readfile($url);
//Retorna uma mensagem de erro dizendo que os parâmetros não foram passados.
//Como se tivesse enviado apenas: www.servico.com.br

$dataReturn = new SoapClient($url); // Essa foi no desespero
//Retorna uma mensagem de erro dizendo que não é um wsdl

$dataReturm = Response::json($url);
//Também dá erro. :(
```

Alguma sugestão para retornar os dados???

Comment: Tem alguma documentação desse serviço?

Comment: Sim, existe a documentação. Quando eu faço a requisição via browser da URL gerada pelo PHP, ele funciona. O problema está exatamente na minha requisição pelo PHP.

Comment: Pode ser que esteja faltando algum header, não?

Comment: Pior que não, o erro se aplica exatamente na ausência da query string, que ele não monta. :(

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**RESOLVIDO**

Pessoal, muito obrigado por todas as respostas. Porém, consegui resolver o problema de forma bem simples. E foi assim:

```
$handle = fopen($url, 'r');
flock($handle, LOCK_SH);
$result = file_get_contents($url);
fclose($handle);
```

> **DICA**
>
> Vale lembrar que dessa forma serve para multiplas requisições, bastando apenas colocar dentro de um loop, como fiz também da seguinte forma:

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $handle = fopen($url, 'r');
    flock($handle, LOCK_SH);
    $result[] = file_get_contents($url);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Ai está a dica pra quem precisar também!!!

Comment: Nesse trecho, `fopen($url, 'rt')`. De onde tirou esse segundo parâmetro, `rt`? Não existe no manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: O `flock()` também não faz sentido pois não faz sentido bloquear a escrita já que não tem como escrever na página de uma url. rsrs.. O mais estranho é que está usando `file_get_contents()`. No final das contas, o `fopen()` não está fazendo nada. rsrs.. Na verdade está fazendo dupla requisição onde o resultado é obtido somente de `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: O estranho é que se eu tiro o `fopen()` e o `flock()`não funciona para muítiplas requisições... Ele não executa nem a primeira requisição... uanto ao `rt` foi um erro de escrita, o correto é apenas `r` como eu dei Ctrl C + Ctrl V, passou despercebido...

Answer (score 2):

Tenta usar o file_get_contents() com HTTP Context Options

```
$getdata = http_build_query(
  [
    'nome' => 'abc',
    'cpf' => 'abc'
  ]
);

$opts = array('https' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $getdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('https://www.servico.com.br', false, $context);
```

Comment: Isso vai gerar um erro. Ele vai falar que o arquivo `www.servico.com.br` não existe, pois não especificou o protocolo. Em php, para consultar uma url é necessário especificar o wrapper ou protocolo, como citei na minha resposta. A sua resposta se aplica melhor em casos onde se usa requisições post. É possível passar o get sem usar stream_context_create.

Comment: Isso é só um exemplo, ele precisa definir o protocolo no primeiro parametro do file_get_contents().
No caso de usar stream é uma boa opção, por que acredito eu que seja necessário passar algo mais no header dessa requisição. Ele precisa dar uma olhada na doc desse serviço

Comment: É bom postar o exemplo certo, para que outros usuários não tenha problemas, entende? só por isso.

Comment: Deu erro: 

[ErrorException]
  file_get_contents(https://www.servico.com.br): failed to open st
  ream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Sim sim, adicionar o protocolo na string

Comment: Com o protocolo também dá erro.

Comment: Quando inclui o protocolo `HTTPS` na string do StackOverflow ele omitiu, mas foi passado com o protocolo sim...

Comment: Perceba que na chave do array de $opts tem 'http', tente usar 'https' se este serviço for https

Comment: Fiz essa mudança no `$opts` alterei para `HTTPS`, o erro que alega a ausência de parâmetro segue aparecendo agora.

Comment: Esse serviço tem doc?

Comment: Sim, possui. As informações está de acordo, por exemplo, eu preciso fazer essa requisição por dentro do código PHP, dá o erro, porém, se eu pego a URL completa que é criada pelo código PHP e jogo no navegador, ele executa tranquilamente.

Comment: Quando você está no browser, está logado nesse serviço?

Comment: Não, é um processo que funciona independente de login.

Comment: Me perdoa, mas será que ao inves de parametros GET não seriam parametros por POST?

Tenta trocar o 'method' na stream para testarmos.

Comment: Já fiz isso também, dá erro do Laravel dizendo que o método requisitado não existe, ele é um GET mesmo...

Answer (score 2):

Bem tecnicamente a função "file_get_contents" já contempla o envio de urls com query strings embutidas, então o que posso pensar é que o erro esta no seu servidor ou mais provavelmente no servidor que recebe, como bloqueio de "user_agent", bloqueio de IP, bloqueio de cabeçalhos entre outros.

**Testar seu Servidor**
Bem para testar seu servidor você pode criar 2 arquivos simples, um que recebe e outro que envia, e exiba esses dados na tela, isso pode indicar que seu servidor esta funcionando corretamente ... como o exemplo abaixo:

*[ Envia ]*

```
<?php
var_dump(file_get_contents("http://seuserver.com.br/recebe.php?nome=abc&cpf=abc&cep=abc"));
?>
```

*[ Recebe ]*

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Caso consiga visualizar os dados que enviou então cai no segundo caso, que o servidor que recebe tem alguma restrição ... a mais comum é a de "user_agent" ou cabeçalho mal formatado, então você pode simular um "agent", pois muitos servidores fazem o bloqueio para justamente não ser acessado por robôs, assim usando as repostas dos colegas, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

*[ Envia ]*

```
<?php
 $opts = array(
  "http" => array(
   "method" => "GET",
   "user_agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36"
 )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents("http://seuserver.com.br/recebe.php?nome=abc&cpf=abc&cep=abc", false, $context);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

*[ Recebe ]*

```
<?php
 print_r($_GET);
 echo "\r\n";
 echo $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
?>
```

Por fim caso essa solução não resolva eu aconselho a partir para algo mais elaborado como usar a extensão [cURL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) ou fazer seu próprio modulo de conexão HTTP usando o [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fsockopen.php).

Comment: Dica:  selecione código e aperte `{}` ou control+K que ele formata sozinho.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente com CURL, use este código:

```
$url = 'https://www.servico.com.br'

$querydata = array(
    'nome' => 'abc',
    'cpf' => 'abc',
    'cep' => 'abc'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($querydata));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$jsonResult = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $jsonResult;
```